# Set backcolor to the button which user clicked

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi all I am creating some button dynamically, and when user click on the button I need to set the BackColor for the selected button to some highlighted color, as per the code what I have written it is applying color for every button, instead of that I need to apply color for the user clicked button

My code for creating buttons is as follows

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    Button btyDynamic = new Button();
    btyDynamic .Click += new EventHandler(btyDynamic _Click);
    btyDynamic .AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    btyDynamic .AutoSize = true;
    btyDynamic .Text = i.ToString();
    btyDynamic .Tag = i.ToString();;
}

protected void btyDynamic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Button btn= sender as Button;
   string strTag= btn.Tag.ToString();
   switch(strTag)
   {
      case "0":
         btn.BackColor=Color.LightSteelBlue;
       break;
     // Like this I am writing, now when in Case2 I need to remove the color of the first button and to show the backcolor of second button
   }
}
```

Comment: So do you want the button color to stay `LightSteelBlue` until the user clicks another button?

Comment: ` SwDevMan81` ya the color stays but when user click another button say `1` I need to remove the BackColor for `0` and apply for `1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could store the last button selected and then reset the `BackColor`:

```
private Button _lastButtonSelected = null;
protected void btyDynamic(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // Set new button back color
   Button btn = sender as Button;
   if(btn != null)
   {
      btn.BackColor = Color.LightSteelBlue;
   }
   // Reset last button color
   if(_lastButtonSelected != null)
   {
      _lastButtonSelected.BackColor = ...; // Put default back color here
   }
   _lastButtonSelected = btn;
}
```

If you want the `BackColor` to remain `LightSteelBlue` if you click the same button twice, you just need to check that the `_lastButtonSelected != btn` as well.

Answer (score 1):

you could make a foreach for all buttons, and remove background for all button not equal to sender. Suppose to save all buttons into an array (_AllButtons). you could write some code like this:

```
Button btn= sender as Button;
foreach(var currentButton in _AllButtons) {
   if(currentButton !=btn) {
        currentButton.BackColor=Color.Transparent;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible algorithm would be:

- create the buttons once as you already do and bind the click event to one handler
- in the click handler first reset all buttons to the standard background color
- in the click handler find the currently clicked button using switch as you already do and set the color of this button

Sample code:

```
Action resetButtonColor = () => 
{
    button1.BackColor = Colors.Red;
    button2.BackColor = Colors.Red
    button3.BackColor = Colors.Red;
};

resetButtonColor();

var selected = Colors.Green;
switch(strTag)
{
    case "1": button1.BackColor = selected;
    case "2": button2.BackColor = selected;
    case "3": button3.BackColor = selected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then You must assign to the click event of this one button explicetely.
All others could have this handler, but the one button should not, because it is too generic handled in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
    Color highLite = Color.Black;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Text = i.ToString();
            b.Tag = null;
            b.Click += b_Click;
            flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(b);
        }
    }

    void b_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        if (b == null)
            return;

        b.BackColor = highLite;

        // clear backcolors
        foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
            if (c != b)
                c.BackColor = SystemColors.Control;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are only setting backcolors of controls you want to set. Make the tag have something unique to tell you that you want to change it.

```
private Color offColor = Color.Red;
private Color onColor = Color.Blue;
private String btyPrefix = "bty";

private void btyDynamic_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control control = (Control)sender;
    // enumerate this.Controls, but if they go into a different container, enumerate over that
    this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
        .Where(c => ((String)c.Tag).Contains(btyPrefix))
        .ToList<Control>()
        .ForEach(c =>
            {
                if (control == c)
                    c.BackColor = onColor;
                else
                    c.BackColor = offColor;
            }
    );
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btyDontChange = new Button();
    btyDontChange.AutoSize = true;
    btyDontChange.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
    btyDontChange.Text = "x";
    btyDontChange.Tag = "something";
    btyDontChange.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    this.Controls.Add(btyDontChange);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        Button btyDynamic = new Button();
        btyDynamic.Click += new EventHandler(btyDynamic_click);
        btyDynamic.AutoSizeMode = AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        btyDynamic.AutoSize = true;
        btyDynamic.Text = i.ToString();
        btyDynamic.Tag = btyPrefix + i.ToString();
        btyDynamic.Location = new Point((i+1) * 50, 0);
        btyDynamic.BackColor = offColor;
        this.Controls.Add(btyDynamic);
    }
}
```